# Clean Up Function Applying Value To Array of Functions In Ramda

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, ramda.js

I would like to take an array of functions and apply a value to them, collecting the results in an array. I have this working, but the `flip` makes it a little convoluted. How can I simplify it?

```
const f1 = v => v + '1';
const f2 = v => v + '2';
const f3 = v => v + '3';

const result = compose(flip(map)([f1, f2, f3]), applyTo);

result('a')  // ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
```

[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20f1%20%3D%20v%20%3D%3E%20v%20%2B%20%271%27%3B%0Aconst%20f2%20%3D%20v%20%3D%3E%20v%20%2B%20%272%27%3B%0Aconst%20f3%20%3D%20v%20%3D%3E%20v%20%2B%20%273%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20compose%28flip%28map%29%28%5Bf1%2C%20f2%2C%20f3%5D%29%2C%20applyTo%29%3B%0A%0Aresult%28%27a%27%29%20%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22a1%22%2C%20%22a2%22%2C%20%22a3%22%5D%0A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`R.juxt`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt) which takes a list of functions and returns a new function that will apply all values it receives to each of the functions in the list, producing a list of the resulting values.

```js
const f1 = v => v + '1'
const f2 = v => v + '2'
const f3 = v => v + '3'

const result = R.juxt([f1, f2, f3])

console.log(result('a'))  // ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```